# Diminuir datas em javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estou tentando utilizar o moment.js mas tá osso, viu?!!!

Tenho 2 campos que retornam a data em PHP no formato dd/mm/yyyy. Quero mostrar num terceiro campo a diferença entre essas datas. Por exemplo: 25/09/2018 e 30/09/2018 a resposta tem que ser 5 dias. Obviamente em PHP já fiz, contudo se o usuário alterar um campo desses atualize no terceiro.

No mesmo exemplo acima, se passar de 25/09/2018 para 26/09/2018 atualizar automático no terceiro campo.

Fiz um fiddle da bagaça: http://jsfiddle.net/becw281u/

Comment: Um bom começo seria dar uma olhada mais aprofundada na documentação, a data que você está passando para a função moment() não está correta. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: Agradeço o comentário, mas olhei a documentação e não entendi muita coisa. Como falei, já tenho a data naquele formato e percebi que precisava alterar seu formato para que o moment.js entendesse, mas não sei como fazer...

Comment: É sempre bom marcar uma resposta como aceita quando a mesma resolveu seu problema. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Ainda tenho reputação baixa, não consigo marcar. Não é má vontade não, por isso postei o agradecimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você que calcular a diferença em dias entre duas datas, certo?

Segue abaixo a alteração no código citado na pergunta:

```js
var dtconclusao = document.getElementById("dtconclusao").value;
var dtfim = document.getElementById("dtfim").value;
var data1 = moment(dtconclusao, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var data2 = moment(dtfim, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var diferenca = data2.diff(data1, 'days');

alert(diferenca);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="dtconclusao" value="25/09/2018" />
<input type="hidden" id="dtfim" value="30/09/2018" />
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado meu caro!

Answer (score 1):

moment.min.js  => 51Kb

momentDoLeo.js =>  1Kb

Use o momentDoLeo.js veja o funcionamento

```js
    //momentDoLeo.js

    var dtconclusao = document.getElementById("dtconclusao").value;
    dtconclusao = dtconclusao.split("/").reverse().join("-");

    var dtfim = document.getElementById("dtfim").value;
    dtfim = dtfim.split("/").reverse().join("-");

    var datafinal = new Date(dtfim);
    var datainicial = new Date(dtconclusao);

    var difDias = (parseInt((datafinal - datainicial) / (24 * 3600 * 1000)));
    
     document.getElementById("numeroDias").value=difDias;
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="dtconclusao" value="25/09/2018" />
<input type="hidden" id="dtfim" value="30/09/2018" />

<input type="text" id="numeroDias" name="numeroDias"/>
```